# Why is waitpid not waiting for a process to quit?

Tags: c, macos, process, pid

I have this simple code written in C and my os is osx:

```
int main() {
    pid_t pid = 1244;
    int pid_status;
    waitpid(pid, &pid_status, 0);
    printf("%i\n",pid_status);
}
```

1244 is the process id for Opera browser running right now:

```
Korays-MacBook-Pro:HelloWorld koraytugay$ ps -p 1244
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1244 ??         0:09.19 /Applications/Opera.app/Contents/MacOS/Opera
```

What I expect to happen is when I run this program, it should simply wait until I close Opera, but what I get is:

```
Korays-MacBook-Pro:HelloWorld koraytugay$ ./koko
1798668342
Korays-MacBook-Pro:HelloWorld koraytugay$ ./koko
1637806134
Korays-MacBook-Pro:HelloWorld koraytugay$ ./koko
1707163702
```

Why is this program directly quitting and what is these different numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`waitpid` is only effective for child processes. See the manual page
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html.

You will find `waitpid` is returning -1. Please check `errno`

Comment: Hmm I did not know that. Thanks. Because I am reading Headfirst C and it exactly says: Question: Can I use waitpid to wait for any process? Answer: You can use waitpid() to wait for any process.

Comment: Sounds like a bad book.

Comment: Would you be okay with replacing the link in your answer with http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html? The site you linked is outdated, unmaintained SEO spam.

Comment: I have not realized that the manual pages for wait have changed. By all means change it. I can always revert if.

Comment: OK. I don't know if this specific one has changed, but I prefer we avoid promoting a site that's just SEO spam and has outdated information in lots of its man pages.

Comment: `waitpid()` might behave differently on MacOS vs Linux

Comment: this project https://github.com/izabera/pm-tools suggests that `waitpid()` should work for all processes not just child processes...